# Handle high-pressure situations of non-legit connections / requests

Tags: security, ddos, spoofing, blacklist

Just read about IP spoofing. Not sure, but it seems that it's possible to enter any ip and make the recipient believe that you are someone else, without it being controlled?

What I perceived is that if I end up under attack and choose to handle this by "blacklisting" the ip address behind the attacker, then there is a high chance that I actually blacklist someone innocent (if the attacker has entered a different ip address than their own)

The probability that the attacker switches to an address that matches and affects one of my regular users is of course very small, but that means I can't stop the attacker and the madness continues.

What approaches do you recommend to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to secure your server is to install fail2ban and confurige it to read your access log(s) to ban ip's for a certain time. There are loads of tutorials on how to install fail2ban, so not going to write that info here. In my 8 years of running web servers I have never had an ip spoofing situation, but atleast with fail2ban you can block an ip for a limited time, thereby decreasing the chances of a DOS, exploit, or something else.

What failban does is, it reads your logs, and based on the regex from its filters it can ban ip's. There are some filters pre-installed with failban, but they are in no way perfect for any server, so some finetuning is needed.

after you installed it and read through the docs I would greatly recomend that you read the Python regex docs so you can write your own regex [Python regex documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Below is a filter I created to ban bad requests one of my servers. You can just edit it to suit your server

```
    [Definition]

badreqcustom = .*mysql.*|.*backup.*|.*wlwmanifest.*|.*xmlrpc.*|.*sleep.*|.*benchmark.*|.*when.*|.*then.*|.*schema.*|.*else.*|.*author.*|.*\.aspx.*|.*wp-admin.*|.*myadmin.*|.*wp-login.*|.*/misc/.*|.*\.rar.*|.*wordpress.*|.*wp-includes.*|.*/tmp/.*|.*js/lib.*|.*charcode.*
badreq = .*sql.*|.*phpmyadmin.*|.*adminer.*|.*alert.*|.*union.*|.*select.*|.*where.*|.*fetch.*|.*proxy.*|.*debug.*|.*phpstorm.*|.*eval-stdin.*|.*phpunit.*|.*invoke.*|.*adminlogin.*|.*admin123.*|.*hack.*|.*login\.php.*|.*404\.php.*|.*blackhat.*|.*cgi-bin.*

failregex = (?i)^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).(?:%(badreq)s|%(badreqcustom)s).*".*".*".*".*".*$
ignoreregex = (?i)^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT).*(madmin|uid|gclid|fbclid|/blog/|/photographers-directory/|/amasty_acart|/vcs/).*"$
```

All the best and goodluck